# Bounded implies closed

Tags: general-topology

Clearly bounded does not imply closed. Where am I screwing up?

Let S denote an arbitrary bounded subset of the reals.
Since S is bounded, any sequence in S must also be bounded.
By Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem all sequences in S must have convergent subsequences. S is sequentially compact, and therefore compact. By the Heine-Borel theorem S is closed and bounded.

I have to admit I've never taken a class in topology, I'm only just now finishing my first class in analysis which is how I ended up confused about the above 'proof'.

Comment: Whilst the sequence will have a convergent subsequence, the limit is only guaranteed to be in $R$, not in $S$. To say the limit is in $S$ we need additional assumptions, such as $S$ is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the point that the fact that $S$ includes a convergent sequence does not mean that it includes its limit.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample to this argument can be $S=(0,1]$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$.

$a_n =\frac{1}{n}$ is in S while its limit point(i.e., $0$) not.